# Text hidding when using shape background in TextView - Android

Tags: android, layout

I want to display a number in the center of a colored circle. My problem is that I have to display the circle and the text at a specific size, but the text is hiding. If I use a larger radius for the circle the text is showing. Here is my code:

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="2"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    />
```

and the shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#0196C0"/>
    <padding android:bottom="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"></padding>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Either you have to give **large radius** or you need to give **less padding**  for your resource xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#0196C0"/>
    <padding android:bottom="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"></padding>
</shape>
```

Comment: This is the right solution.